# save not working properlly

Tags: php, kohana

controller

userdetails.php

```
class Controller_Userdetails extends Controller { 
    public function action_index() {
        $view = new View('userdetails/index');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
     public function action_add() {//load adddetails.php
        $userdetails = new Model_Userdetails();         
        $view = new View('userdetails/adddetails');
        $view->set("userdetails", $userdetails);         
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
    public function action_post() {//save the post data
        $userdetails_id = $this->request->param('id');
        $userdetails = new Model_Userdetails($userdetails_id);
        $userdetails->values($_POST);       
        $userdetails->save();          
        $this->request->redirect('index.php/userdetails'); 
    }

}
```

views

adddetails.php

```
<?php echo Form::open('userdetails/post/'.$userdetails->id); ?>
    <?php echo Form::label("first_name", "First Name"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input("first_name", $userdetails->first_name); ?>
    <br />    
    <?php echo Form::label("last_name", "Last Name"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input("last_name", $userdetails->last_name); ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo Form::label("email", "Email"); ?>
    <?php echo Form::input("email", $userdetails->email); ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo Form::submit("submit", "Submit"); ?>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

I am trying to insert the data into database.The name and email field are loading correctly,if i enter values and hit enter it is redirecting to other page but objects not saved in database.Need help to solve this.

Comment: Try doing `try { $userdetails->save(); } catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e) { echo Debug::vars($e->errors()); die(); }` To check for validation issues.

Comment: Where should i find the form errors,if i use try & catch block.

Comment: They should be on the page, if there are any

Comment: can you post you Model_Userdetails code?

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes find problems in saving while using

```
$userdetails->values($_POST);
```

try using

```
$userdetails->first_name = $this->request->post('first_name');
$userdetails->last_name= $this->request->post('last_name');
$userdetails->email= $this->request->post('email');
```

Comment: anytime ^_^ don't forget to accept my solution if no better one is around , kinda need the 15 rep :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the model is an ORM model (`class Model_Userdetails extends ORM {}`), you should use `ORM::factory()` to load the model. Furthermore it's recommended to use the `expected` parameter to be sure only the values you want to be inserted are used.

```
$user_details = ORM::factory('Userdetails');
$user_details->values($this->request->post(), 
    array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
);
$user_details->save();
```